# Prestashop module tab slider random product

Tags: random, prestashop

This is Tab category slider module of Prestashop CMS, it shows last added productes, i need to show random products.

I will add more info if it will be needed

sry for my bad English.

Thanks for help guys.

```
class postabcateslider1 extends Module {
    private $spacer_size = '5'; 
    private $_postErrors  = array();
    private $_html= null;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->name         = 'postabcateslider1';
        $this->tab          = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version      = '1.5';
        $this->author       = 'posthemes';
        $this->displayName  = $this->l('Category Tabs Slider 1');
        $this->description  = $this->l('Category Tabs Slider 1');
        parent :: __construct();

    }

    public function install() {

    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_on_row', 4);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_limit', 30);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_tab_effect', 'wiggle');
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_on_row', 4);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_width', 150);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_height', 200);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_min_item', 1);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_max_item', 5);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_speed_slide', 3000);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_a_speed', 500);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_show_arrow', 0);
    Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_show_ctr', 0);

    $arrayDefault = array('CAT3','CAT4','CAT5');
    $cateDefault = implode(',',$arrayDefault);
    Configuration::updateGlobalValue($this->name . '_list_cate',$cateDefault);

        return parent :: install()

            && $this->registerHook('top')
        /*  && $this->registerHook('displayHome') */
            && $this->registerHook('blockPosition2')
            //&& $this->registerHook('displayHome')
            && $this->registerHook('header')
            && $this->registerHook('actionOrderStatusPostUpdate')
            && $this->registerHook('addproduct')
            && $this->registerHook('updateproduct')
            && $this->registerHook('deleteproduct');
    }

      public function uninstall() {
        Configuration::deleteByName($this->name . '_list_cate');
        $this->_clearCache('postabcateslider1.tpl');
        return parent::uninstall();
    }


    public function psversion() {
        $version=_PS_VERSION_;
        $exp=$explode=explode(".",$version);
        return $exp[1];
    }


    public function hookHeader($params){
        // if ($this->psversion()==5){
            // $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'postabcateslider.css', 'all');
            // $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'animate.delay.css', 'all');
            // $this->context->controller->addCSS(($this->_path).'animate.min.css', 'all');

        // } else {
            // Tools::addCSS(($this->_path).'postabcateslider.css');
            // Tools::addCSS(($this->_path).'animate.delay.css');
            // Tools::addCSS(($this->_path).'animate.min.css');

        // }
    }

    public function hookblockPosition2($params) {
            $nb = Configuration::get($this->name . '_p_limit');
            $product_on_row = Configuration::get($this->name . '_p_on_row');
            $arrayCategory = array();
            $catSelected = Configuration::get($this->name . '_list_cate');
            $cateArray = explode(',', $catSelected); 
            $id_lang =(int) Context::getContext()->language->id;
            $id_shop = (int) Context::getContext()->shop->id;
            $arrayProductCate = array();
            foreach($cateArray as $id_category) {
                $id_category = str_replace('CAT','',$id_category);
                $category = new Category((int) $id_category, (int) $id_lang, (int) $id_shop);
                $categoryProducts = $category->getProducts($this->context->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5),'date_add','DESC');
                if($categoryProducts) {
                    $arrayProductCate[] = array('id' => $id_category, 'name'=> $category->name, 'product' => $categoryProducts);
                }
            }

            $options = array(
                'p_width' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_p_width'),
                'p_height' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_p_height'),

                'speed_slide' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_speed_slide'),
                'a_speed' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_a_speed'),
                 'show_des' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_show_des'),
                'show_arrow' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_show_arrow'),
                'show_ctr' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_show_ctr'),
                'min_item' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_min_item'),
                'max_item' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_max_item'),  'show_price' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_show_price'),

            );

            $this->context->smarty->assign('slideOptions', $options);
            $this->smarty->assign(array(
                'productCates' => $arrayProductCate,
                'add_prod_display' => Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
                'homeSize' => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('home')),
                'product_on_row' => $product_on_row,
                'tab_effect' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_tab_effect'),
                'title' => Configuration::get($this->name . '_title'),

            ));
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'postabcateslider1.tpl');
    }

      public function getContent() {
        $output = '<h2>' . $this->displayName . '</h2>';
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitPosTabCate')) {
            if (!sizeof($this->_postErrors))
                $this->_postProcess();
            else {
                foreach ($this->_postErrors AS $err) {
                    $this->_html .= '<div class="alert error">' . $err . '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
        return $output . $this->_displayForm();
    }

    public function getSelectOptionsHtml($options = NULL, $name = NULL, $selected = NULL) {
        $html = "";
        $html .='<select name =' . $name . ' style="width:130px">';
        if (count($options) > 0) {
            foreach ($options as $key => $val) {
                if (trim($key) == trim($selected)) {
                    $html .='<option value=' . $key . ' selected="selected">' . $val . '</option>';
                } else {
                    $html .='<option value=' . $key . '>' . $val . '</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        $html .= '</select>';
        return $html;
    }

    private function _postProcess() {

        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_list_cate', implode(',', Tools::getValue('list_cate')));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_on_row', Tools::getValue('p_on_row'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_limit', Tools::getValue('p_limit'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_tab_effect', Tools::getValue('tab_effect'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_title', Tools::getValue('title'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_height', Tools::getValue('p_height'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_width', Tools::getValue('p_width'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_p_limit', Tools::getValue('p_limit'));

        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_speed_slide', Tools::getValue('speed_slide'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_a_speed', Tools::getValue('a_speed'));

        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_show_arrow', Tools::getValue('show_arrow'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_show_ctr', Tools::getValue('show_ctr'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_min_item', Tools::getValue('min_item'));
        Configuration::updateValue($this->name . '_max_item', Tools::getValue('max_item'));

        $this->_html .= '<div class="conf confirm">' . $this->l('Settings updated') . '</div>';
    }

    private function _displayForm(){ 
        $spacer = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $this->spacer_size);

     $tabEffect = array();
        $tabEffect = array(
            'none' => 'None', 
            'hinge' => 'Hinge', 
            'flash' => 'Flash', 
            'shake' => 'Shake',
            'bounce' => 'Bounce',
            'tada' => 'Tada' ,
            'swing' => 'Swing', 
            'wobble' => 'Wobble', 
            'pulse' => 'Pulse', 
            'flip' => 'Flip', 
            'flipInX' => 'FlipInX', 
            'flipInY' => 'FlipInY', 
            'fadeIn' => 'FadeIn', 
            'bounceInUp' => 'BounceInUp', 
            'fadeInLeft' => 'FadeInLeft', 
            'rollIn' => 'RollIn', 
            'lightSpeedIn' => 'LightSpeedIn', 
            'wiggle' => 'Wiggle', 
            'rotateIn' => 'RotateIn', 
            'rotateInUpLeft' => 'RotateInUpLeft', 
            'rotateInUpRight' => 'RotateInUpRight'

        );
         $this->_html .= '
        <form action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" method="post">
                  <fieldset>
                    <legend><img src="../img/admin/cog.gif" alt="" class="middle" />' . $this->l('Settings') . '</legend>
                    <label>'.$this->l('Title: ').'</label>
                    <div class="margin-form">
                            <input type = "text"  name="title" value ='.(Tools::getValue('title')?Tools::getValue('title'): Configuration::get($this->name.'_title')).' ></input>
                    </div>
                    <label>'.$this->l('Effect Tab: ').'</label>
                    <div class="margin-form">';
                       $this->_html .= $this->getSelectOptionsHtml($tabEffect,'tab_effect',   (Tools::getValue('tab_effect') ? Tools::getValue('tab_effect') : Configuration::get($this->name . '_tab_effect')));
                       $this->_html .='
                    </div>';

                    $this->_html .= '<label>' . $this->l('Show Link/Label Category: ') . '</label>';
                    $this->_html .= '<div class="margin-form">';
                    $this->_html .= '<select multiple="multiple" name ="list_cate[]" style="width: 200px; height: 160px;">';
                    // BEGIN Categories
                    $id_lang = (int) Context::getContext()->language->id;
                    $this->getCategoryOption(1, (int) $id_lang, (int) Shop::getContextShopID());
                    $this->_html .= '</select>
                    </div>';
                    $this->_html .='

                              <label>' . $this->l('Show Next/Back control: : ') . '</label>
                    <div class="margin-form">';
                    $this->_html .= $this->getSelectOptionsHtml(array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'), 'show_arrow', (Tools::getValue('title') ? Tools::getValue('show_arrow') : Configuration::get($this->name . '_show_arrow')));
                    $this->_html .='
                                </div>
                                <label>' . $this->l('Show navigation control: : ') . '</label>
                                 <div class="margin-form">';
                    $this->_html .= $this->getSelectOptionsHtml(array(0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'), 'show_ctr', (Tools::getValue('title') ? Tools::getValue('show_ctr') : Configuration::get($this->name . '_show_ctr')));
                    $this->_html .='
                                </div>
                     <label>'.$this->l('Products Limit: ').'</label>
                    <div class="margin-form">
                            <input type = "text"  name="p_limit" value ='.(Tools::getValue('p_limit')?Tools::getValue('p_limit'): Configuration::get($this->name.'_p_limit')).' ></input>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submitPosTabCate" value="'.$this->l('Update').'" class="button" />
                     </fieldset>
        </form>';
        return $this->_html;
    }


     private function getCategoryOption($id_category = 1, $id_lang = false, $id_shop = false, $recursive = true) {
        $cateCurrent = Configuration::get($this->name . '_list_cate');  
        $cateCurrent = explode(',', $cateCurrent);
        $id_lang = $id_lang ? (int)$id_lang : (int)Context::getContext()->language->id;
        $category = new Category((int)$id_category, (int)$id_lang, (int)$id_shop);

        if (is_null($category->id))
            return;

        if ($recursive)
        {
            $children = Category::getChildren((int)$id_category, (int)$id_lang, true, (int)$id_shop);
            $spacer = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $this->spacer_size * (int)$category->level_depth);
        }

        $shop = (object) Shop::getShop((int)$category->getShopID());
                if (in_array('CAT'.(int)$category->id, $cateCurrent)) {
                    $this->_html .= '<option value="CAT'.(int)$category->id.'" selected ="selected" >'.(isset($spacer) ? $spacer : '').$category->name.' ('.$shop->name.')</option>';
                } else {
                    $this->_html .= '<option value="CAT'.(int)$category->id.'">'.(isset($spacer) ? $spacer : '').$category->name.' ('.$shop->name.')</option>';
                }

        if (isset($children) && count($children))
            foreach ($children as $child)
                $this->getCategoryOption((int)$child['id_category'], (int)$id_lang, (int)$child['id_shop']);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution by myself! Thanks for dawnvote

you need to edit this code

```
$categoryProducts = $category->getProducts($this->context->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5),'date_add','DESC');
            if($categoryProducts) {
                $arrayProductCate[] = array('id' => $id_category, 'name'=> $category->name, 'product' => $categoryProducts);
            }
```

with it

```
$categoryProducts = $category->getProducts($this->context->language->id, 0, ($nb ? $nb : 5));
shuffle($categoryProducts);
            if($categoryProducts) {
                $arrayProductCate[] = array('id' => $id_category, 'name'=> $category->name, 'product' => $categoryProducts);
            }
```